# Text Classification in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, text-mining

New to R, and am trying to do text classification. I am using R package [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) to convert raw txt data into matrix. Here's the relevant code snippet.

```
 col <- Corpus(DirSource(path),
                readerControl = list(reader = readPlain,
                language = "en",
                load = TRUE)))

 tdm <-  TermDocumentMatrix(col, control = list(tokenize = NGramTokenizer))
```

I have the following questions:

1) Feature selection

I need to do chi-squared or information gain based feature selection on my data. Which R packages can I look at? I came across at caret and boruta but they do not seem to be appropriate for what I am wanting to do.

2) Handling new (unseen) instances

Let's say I have trained my model using my training set. When the test set comes in, I would need to pass it through same filters (stemming, stopword removal,  tf-idf weighting, feature selection etc.). I have no idea how to do this !

Any hint/help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an answer already, so I'll close it for now so user4581 had a chance to access his answer when possibly answering your new questions. Then it will be deleted as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding feature selection, as you described, depends on the text content ! How do you classify them manually ?! Because of some impression or words ?!(negative - positive) (happy - sad - neutral). Frequency of words could be also informative. check out [this package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper).

There are several review and papers like [this](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/FrankAndBouckaertPKDD06new.pdf) on net.

You can define your own kernel [check kernel methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_methods), in order to put similar text together and distinguish dissimilar. check string kernels from [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/rtexttools/)

For implementation for text classification in R, look at [this list](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) and find your interest method and package.

To address your second question, I can say, do everything(Feature extraction - and all other you mention) + label of the class. Then choose part of data, say 70% and make your own model. Afterward, run your model on the unseen data(30%) and check its output with actual label. then you simply can calculate the accuracy of model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As mentioned in my question, I am in fact using the tm package for preprocessing my data. Actually what I was wanting to know is (1) If there are off the shelf tools for feature subset selection (2) How the transformations (like tf-idf for example) would be applied to TEST set (for example: tf-idf computations on test set would still need to be done on the scale of the training set) - I was hoping to see some code snippets to help with this. But anyway, now I think I will pose these questions separately.

Comment: Some keywords like "dimension reduction", "subset selection", could be helpful to look through here, before throwing question ... and still I am not sure if I get your second question properly ...